# How to Set Value to a Named Range with PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php

The code below is using the PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet library to load an Excel spreadsheet, access a named range within the spreadsheet, set a new value for that named range, and save the modified spreadsheet. The problem is that the cell value is not set and no error is thrown either.
I have verified the existence of a cell named "test" within the spreadsheet.

When the saved Workbook is opened in Excel, an error is displayed:

> Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\NamedRange;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

// Load the spreadsheet file
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load('path/to/your/spreadsheet.xlsx');

// Get the named range
$namedRange = $spreadsheet->getNamedRange('test');

// Set the value of the named range
$namedRange->setValue('hello');

// Save the changes
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('path/to/save/modified/spreadsheet.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the NamedRange class in PhpSpreadsheet does not have a getCellCollection() method. Instead, you can retrieve the cell range associated with the named range and iterate over the cells within that range to set the desired value

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

// Load the spreadsheet file
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load('path/to/your/spreadsheet.xlsx');

// Get the named range
$namedRange = $spreadsheet->getNamedRange('test');

// Get the cell range address for the named range
$rangeAddress = $namedRange->getRange();

// Get the worksheet associated with the named range
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName($namedRange->getWorksheetName());

// Set the value for each cell in the named range
foreach ($worksheet->getCellCollection($rangeAddress) as $cell) {
    $cell->setValue('hello');
}

// Save the changes
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('path/to/save/modified/spreadsheet.xlsx');
```

Make sure to replace 'path/to/your/spreadsheet.xlsx' with the actual path to your spreadsheet file, and 'path/to/save/modified/spreadsheet.xlsx' with the desired path to save the modified spreadsheet. Also, replace 'test' with the name of your named range.

This updated code retrieves the cell range address associated with the named range and then uses the getCellCollection() method on the worksheet to iterate over the cells within that range.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\NamedRange::getCellCollection(

Comment: The correct method name is getCellCollection (with a lowercase "c"), not getCellCollectio.
foreach ($worksheet->getCellCollection($rangeAddress) as $cell) {
    $cell->setValue('hello');
}